# Socket.io not receiving messages on client

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I've been trying to test websocket using angular and nestjs using [this](https://qiita.com/YutaSaito1991/items/26d25ae6ccf89fb25115) tutorial.

This is the gateway from my Nestjs project.

```
import {
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
  WsResponse,
  MessageBody
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway(3001)
export class EventsGateway {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage('message')
  handleMessage(@MessageBody() data: any): WsResponse<string> {
    return { event: 'response', data: data };
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('broadcast')
  broadcast(@MessageBody() data: any): void {
    this.server.emit('broadcast', 'response')
  }
}
```

This is the service from my Angular project.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService {
  private url = 'http://localhost:3001';
  private socket;

  connect() {
    this.socket = io(this.url);
  }

  emit(emitName: string, data?) {
    this.socket.emit(emitName, data);
  }

  on(onName: string) {
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket.on(onName, (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });

      return () => { this.socket.disconnect(); };
    });
    return observable;
  }
}
```

However, the results is not what I expected. The client was unable to retrieve websocket data.
You can clone my repository [here](https://github.com/dkregen/test-websocket).

Please help!

Comment: Looking at your dependencies, it was probbaly a socket.io version mismatch. Nest (at least until v8) only supports socket.io v2, whereas on the client side you have socket.io-client v3 which uses the socket.iov3 engine. These two engines are incompatible. There is an open issue about this and a planned fix for the next major release

Comment: @JayMcDoniel It migh be. Because I got the same symptom on Angular too. I used 2 years old non-typings socket.io code right now and it worked like this problem is nothing. But, NPM should help us picking a correct version and it doesn't. 

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching awhile now on the internet to fix this problem but I couldn't find one that work. It might be Nest bugs, it could be socket.io problems with their typing, or any other else.

So, my best approach currently for this problem is using basic express solution and ignore Nestjs approach completely.

**First uninstall Nest's socket.io.**

```
npm uninstall @nestjs/websockets @nestjs/platform-socket.io @types/socket.io
```

**Second install express and socket.io**

For this one, I will use the known working version.

```
npm install --save express@4.17.1 socket.io@3.0.3
```

Or you can use current version

```
npm install --save express socket.io
```

**Third,** I want to keep Nestjs to be able to communicate with the websocket. So, I will put the socket inside a service. This code bellow will create `msg.service.ts` file under ws directory.

```
nest g s /ws/msg
```

**Finally,** I put the websocket code inside `msg.service.ts` file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class MsgService {

  private readonly PORT = '3030';
  private readonly app;
  private readonly http;
  private readonly io;
  private i: number = 0;

  constructor() {
    this.app = require('express')();
    this.http = require('http').Server(this.app);
    this.io = require('socket.io')(this.http, { cors: { origin: '*', } });

    this.http.listen(this.PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Socket.IO server running at http://localhost:${this.PORT}/`);
      this.loop();
    });
  }

  // Test broadcast every second.
  loop() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.i++;
      this.io.emit('broadcast', this.i);
      console.log(this.i);
      this.loop();
    }, (1 * 1000));
  };

}
```

That's all. The websocket will run when the Nestjs code started.

I do not know yet what kind of performance issues will caused but, I think it's worth it because we do not bothered anymore with the Nestjs future version of bugs.

Comment: you could have used a socketio-client with version2, also from version 8 nestjs is now working with socketio v4.